# Front end label configuration in spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jstl

I would like to have a `external property` (which has label name & value pairs) for each jsp pages in my web application.

I've done in this way like simply reading property file in a Map and placing in jsp using `expression language`.

Is there any other methodology to handle these in Java/Spring?

Answer (score 0):

You can have these as message properties

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

This also explains this in detail - http://www.journaldev.com/2610/spring-mvc-internationalization-i18n-and-localization-l10n-example

If you need these to be by locale, you can use localechangeInterceptor also.

You can PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer for  external properties (eg the systemPropertiesMode property)

http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring

There are also more ways to do this like http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/01/27/how-to-load-external-resources-files-into-spring-context/

```
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>locale\customer\messages</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

[spring mvc and ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939619/spring-mvc-and-reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource)

Comment: I've referred this but it's not my scope. I'd like to keep property files externally (outside of WAR).

Comment: how about PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ? does that help?

Comment: And am looking for individual configuration property for each jsp in the application also.

Comment: does PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer do the  job?

Comment: Am not sure about that

Comment: try this...http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/118767-internationalization-and-external-resource-file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72896/discussion-between-surendar-kannan-and-paul-john).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is another way to show the labels in spring and this one is the best practice code.

[enter link description here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/) This will explain you how to use `<spring:message code="label.viewUser" />`  in your project.